# From hbm to JPA annotations (subclasses)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I'm updating my code to JPA and I get a error when used the discriminator

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("3")
public class WidgetContainer extends Square {
   ...
}
```

Square.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "square")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "squareType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Square implements Indexable, Serializable{
   ...
}
```

I get this error

```
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 1 was not of the specified subclass: sym.domain.Square (Discriminator: 3)
```

Comment: when do you get this error?

Comment: when get the discriminator 3 in a query

Comment: Can you show the code for that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid things happens... I miss add this subclass to the hibernate configuration

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        name="sessionFactoriBla"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                                .......
                <value>com.domain.WidgetContainer</value>
                                ......
            </list>
        </property>
...
```

sorry

Comment: which seems to have nothing to do with JPA, since you said you were moving to JPA

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue which was solved by adding this annotation:

```
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
```

to the root of the inheritance structure (Square in your case).  I don't know if there is a pure JPA way to achieve this.

[Java API for DiscriminatorOptions](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html-single/API_Documentation/files/javadoc/org/hibernate/annotations/DiscriminatorOptions.html)

Comment: It's a way to configure how Hibernate implements Discriminators, but I agree with you it doesn't seem quite right since the object is already correctly annotated.